# Full screen overlay menu (pure css) - Close it by clicking the menu link

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="op">
</input><div class="lower">
<label for="op">click the text</label>
</div>
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
<label for="op"></label>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
@import "http://webfonts.ru/import/notcourier.css";
body{   background:url('http://cs625217.vk.me/v625217712/1a11c/0QgZ5V0MWEo.jpg')
}
.lower{
width:340px;
margin:10% auto;
padding:50px;
background:white;
opacity:0.8;
color:black;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px black;
border:30px solid white;
}
.lower:hover{
background:black;
color:white;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px white;
border:30px solid black;
}
input{
display:none;
}
.lower label{
font-family: 'NotCourierSans';
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:40px;
text-align:center;
}
.lower label:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}
.overlay{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.overlay label{
width: 58px;
height:58px;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 20px;
background: url('http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/img/cross.png');
z-index: 100;
cursor:pointer;
}
.overlay nav {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
height: 60%;
font-size: 54px;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.overlay ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
.overlay ul li {
display: block;
height: 20%;
height: calc(100% / 5);
min-height: 54px;
}
.overlay ul li a {
font-weight: 300;
display: block;
color: white;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
transition: color 0.2s;
font-family: 'NotCourierSans';
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.overlay ul li a:hover,
.overlay ul li a:focus {
color: #849368;
}
.lower~.overlay-hugeinc{
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}
#op:checked~.overlay-hugeinc{
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.overlay-hugeinc nav {
-moz-perspective: 300px;
}
.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
opacity: 0.4;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-25%) rotateX(35deg);
transform: translateY(-25%) rotateX(35deg);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}
#op:checked~.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
#op:not(:checked)~.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
-webkit-transform: translateY(25%) rotateX(-35deg);
transform: translateY(25%) rotateX(-35deg);
}
```

[Full screen overlay menu (pure css)](http://codepen.io/vladaoleynik/pen/vExKxJ)

Hello, I'm using this code to make an overlay menu with just css. Its works fine but I want it to close when I click a menu link, not just the close icon.

This will be an one page design website, so the menu ideally will slide down and away and the new content displayed.

Comment: why close it just mention the page in anchor it will redirect on click of the link .

Comment: It's an one page design. When I click the menu it will slide down. Sorry if I use the wrong term menu link

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info. I pasted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try including data-toggle and data-target selectors on your menu list items.

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle=".onclick_class" data-target=".target_class">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Sorry, im not very familiar with data-toggle and data-target. Can you change the original code and show me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.overlay ul li a').click(function() {
    $('#op').attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
});
```

I was trying to fix it with just css but no progress. Then I try using jquery and it's working. If you have a better solution please post. Thanks all.

Comment: Hi Tiago. i tried your above solution in your own codepen example but it didn't work. Did you found a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to use jQuery for the page load time/performance issue, you could have turned each menu item into a checkbox.  Since your site is a single page, using checkbox for navigation would have simplified your code as well; killing two birds with one stone. :D

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I have the same issue with mine: https://codepen.io/NickDimou/pen/VwKemQa?editors=1100